# How do I "link from library" to a heirarchy of objects?

Tags: linked-data

I'm building a series of rooms, and I've broken the individual 3d models down into a set of smaller files to make them easier to work with:

#### Floors

This .blend contains the basic primitives for walls, floors, etc:

[image]

#### Rooms

This .blend file contains a set of empties that combine the primitives from 'floors.blend' into individual rooms:

[image]

Notice each item in this .blend is linked from the .floors file so there is no instance mesh duplication.

#### Level

Now building the level...

How do I import the entire hierarchy of objects I've created in 'rooms.blend' (for example Room.Door.1), into my level?

When I tried 'Link from Library' and select the root node, it only links to the root, to doesn't include any child objects.

It looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I know there is no quick way to link parented hierarchies like that unfortunately. I would say either name your objects appropriately with some naming scheme like adding "room1" as prefix or suffix to the name so you can filter them by name while linking; or group them together in the original file by room and then link that group instead. If you link all objects belonging to the hierarchy at once I think the parent relationship is kept

Comment: Wow; is there really no easier way to import other blender objects. There isn't even an Import .blend option. I guess the easiest solution is to export those things as .fbx files and then import those .fbx files.